# Regex Pattern not working

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to find the following pattern in the string:

```
"{xxxxx$ppp>5}&&{xxxxx.ppp==5}"
```

I used the regex :

```
"[{a-z$.a-z==><0-9}||&&{a-z$.a-z==><0-9}]"
```

but in this case the character `"&&"` is not included in the String.Can someone tell what is wrong in the regex pattern

Comment: Please go through some [Regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) [Tutorial](http://regexone.com/)

Comment: Do you want to find the exact pattern?

Comment: {xxxxx\\$ppp>5}(&&)?{xxxxx\\.ppp==5}
Would match the strings "{xxxxx$ppp>5}&&{xxxxx.ppp==5}" and "{xxxxx$ppp>5}{xxxxx.ppp==5}"

Comment: When I pass the String with the given string I get the following String "{xxxxx$ppp>5}{xxxxx.ppp==5}", it cannot identify the "&&" symbol in middle,though I am giving it in my regex pattern.

Comment: "&&" should be the part of te String like this "{xxxxx$ppp>5}&&{xxxxx.ppp==5}"

Comment: & isn't a reserved character in regex, it shouldn't need escaping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
// prints true
System.out.println("{xxxxx$ppp>5}&&{xxxxx.ppp==5}"
      .matches("\\{[a-z]+\\$[a-z]+>[0-9]\\}&&\\{[a-z]+\\.[a-z]+==[0-9]\\}"));
```

***EDIT** : (in response to OP's comments below)*

```
String input = "{xxxxx$ppp>5}&&{xxxxx.ppp==5}";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\{[a-z0-9]+[$.][a-z0-9]+[><=]=?[0-9]\\}")
                         .matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group()); // {xxxxx$ppp>5}
}                                        // {xxxxx.ppp==5}
```

Comment: The correct regex is "[{a-zA-Z$.a-zA-Z==><0-9}\\&&{a-zA-Z$.a-zA-Z==><0-9}]" found it myself

Comment: Do you realize that using `[]` around makes it a regex character class? That means your regex would perhaps match your input string in reverse (or any other permutation) as well.

Comment: Your regex fetches everything with "&&", but what I want is only the patterns excluding &&. i.e everything inside {}

Comment: @Phalguni, in your Qn you clearly say: `I used this regex ... but the character "&&" is not included in the String` and now you're just contradicting yourself by saying `it fetches everything with "&&"`. I think you need a break :)

Comment: sorry my mistake:) I found this time I guess how about this "\\{[a-z0-9]+(\\$|\\.)[a-z0-9]+(>|<|==)[0-9]\\}"

Comment: Yep, this looks better. But, can the input include `>=` or `<=` as well?

Comment: @Phalguni, use this: `"\\{[a-z0-9]+[$.][a-z0-9]+[><=]=?[0-9]\\}"`. It takes care of `lt`, `gt` and also uses character classes `[]` instead of pipes `|` which don't perform as well.

Comment: I modified the regex to the following "[a-z0-9]+[$.][a-z0-9]+[><=][0-9'a-z]+(\\.[0-9][0-9]?)?", to pick the following strings "items.qty>50" and "items.sku=='ggg' ", buit in this case second one is not getting parsed can you tell what is going wrong in the regex.

Comment: @Phalguni, you forgot to add `=?` after `[><=]` as in my regex above.

Answer (score 0):

```
\\{[a-zA-Z]+\\$[a-zA-Z]+>5}&&{[0-9]+\\.[a-zA-Z]+==[0-9]+\\}
```

From looking at your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908136/modification-on-string-through-regex), I've assumed you want xxx and ppp to be any alphabetical string, and 5 to be any numeric string.

Comment: I got the following exception Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition
{[a-zA-Z]+\$[a-zA-Z]+>5}(&&)?{[0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+==[0-9]+}
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)

Comment: Forgot to escape the { }, my bad.

Comment: Hey it still throws exception. I found the solution myself. The correct regex is "[{a-zA-Z$.a-zA-Z==><0-9}\\&&{a-zA-Z$.a-zA-Z==><0-9}]"

Comment: Your regex is a really dubious character class it will match the individual characters of your string but not the string itself